# string to double issue, dot is removed

Tags: c#, typeconverter

I have a string value, containing longitude or latitude value.

However, when I try to convert this to a double, I end up with a number where the dot is removed and placed at the end.

This is not what I want. What am I missing?

This is the value I get: `200,5,1.4928184,0.1609203` and this is the method I use to get the value:

```
 var responseBytes = ms.ToArray();
                var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                var coords = encoding.GetString(responseBytes);
                var parts = coords.Split(new char[] { ',' });


//this piece of code returns me wrong values! When I debug this piece parts[2] is exactly 1.4928184
                return new Coordinaat(Double.Parse(parts[2]),
                    Double.Parse(parts[3]));
```

See code example below for constructor:

```
 public Coordinaat(double lat, double lon)
        {
            this.Latitude = lat;
            this.Longitude = lon;
        }
```

Output:
`lat 114928184 lon 01609203` --> where did my dots go to??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably under a culture (e.g German) which is causing this effect. Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCultre` while parsing.

```
Double.Parse("123.22",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Dutch system probably same as German culture. This fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Or under Dutch culture (or almost any continental European culture).

Comment: @dtb, had the similar experience with German culture, didn't know that its true for most of the European culture

Comment: To elaborate, under a Dutch culture, the separator `"."` is considered some arbitrary "grouping" of the digits (thousands separator, `NumberGroupSeparator`), and `","` is the character separating the integer part from the decimals, so `42.012.345,67` is a "good" Dutch number. And `1.4928184` will be the same as `14.928.184` (the grouping separators are more or less ignored, only commas matter).

Comment: I get the same problem even  when using invariantCulture